# Angular 2: Ignore first trigger of ngOnChanges?

Tags: angular

Is there any angular 2 way to skip the first trigger of ngOnChanges? Currently I am using this naive approach to ignore it:

```
isFirst: boolean = true;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (this.isFirst) {
      this.isFirst = false;
      return;
    }
    console.log(changes);
  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/SimpleChange-class.html#!#isFirstChange-anchor

```
if(changes['prop'].isFirstChange()) {
}
```

Comment: Ah! I missed that part in documentation. Thanks :)

Comment: Or use `if(changes['prop'].previousValue)`

Answer (score 10):

To add onto the previous answer and explain this a bit more...

`changes` is an array of objects that have been changed. So if you have an input `myInput`, you'll need to access that object within the changes array by doing `changes['myInput']`. `myInput` contains:

- `previousValue` - previous value of the object (before the change)
- `currentValue` - current value of the object that has been changed
- `firstChange` - boolean on whether this is the first time there has
  been a change (note this will be true when the component intializes
  and false otherwise) - `isFirstChange()` will return true if this is the first change.

Code:

```
//your input
@Input() myInput: any;

ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
  //check if this isn't the first change of myInput
  if(!changes['myInput'].isFirstChange()) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have many inputs, but can't tell for sure which one of them is set, you may use

- [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to retrieve all changes as an array
- [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check whether any of the changes has `isFirstChange` set

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const isFirstChange = Object.values(changes).some(c => c.isFirstChange());
}
```

**Beware:** If no `@Input` is set at all, `isFirstChange` will be `false` because `Array.some` stops at the first `true` value.

Answer (score 2):

For a safer side, I always do this and it works like a charm.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: { [key: string]: SimpleChange }): void {
if (changes['propertyName'] &&
      changes['propertyName'].previousValue !== undefined &&
      !changes['propertyName'].isFirstChange() ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if **any changes** has been made here is what you could do :

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    Object.keys(changes).forEach(key => {
      if (changes[key].previousValue != undefined) {
          // Do your stuff
      }
    })
  }
```